# Laravel - is there a way to include inputs in a validation redirect using $request->validate()?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, controller

I'm swapping over from creating a `Validator` instance to calling a direct `$request->validate([ ... ])` in my controller. Previously, I could specify whether the redirect should include errors and inputs:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255'
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect('route')
        ->withErrors($validator) <--- this line
        ->withInput();           <--- this line
}
```

However, with the new syntax, the options are removed as the validation failure redirect is handled automatically:

```
$request->validate([
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255'
]);

// code is error free
```

The errors are returned to the view in the same way as `withErrors()`, but not the inputs. Is there a way to include the inputs with the new syntax?

Comment: There's docs here [Repopulating forms](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#repopulating-forms). I guess what you want is to set the old values back in the form, you can use `{{ old('name') }}` for that, like `<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">`

Comment: @geertjanknapen that's all in place, the issue I've got is that the $request->validate method doesn't return the inputs to be used in the view :)

Comment: It should. `When Laravel generates a redirect response due to a validation error, the framework will automatically flash all of the request's input to the session. This is done so that you may conveniently access the input during the next request and repopulate the form that the user attempted to submit`. What are you using to try to get the input back out?

Comment: @aynber `<input type="text" name="title" value="{{ old('title') }}">` or variations of that - the same as it was before

Comment: @Dan and currently that gets you the correct 'old' value in the inputs or not? If not we're probably going to need to see some more code..

Comment: @geertjanknapen it got the values when using the original `Validator` instance but doesn't with the `$request->validate()` method call

Comment: the inputs are flashed as well as the errors, by default, `Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler@convertValidationExceptionToResponse -> @invalid`